# What is the proper way to use the `Sequelize.fn` method to format a SQLite3 datetime?

Tags: sqlite, sequelize.js

I'm experimenting with Sequelize.js using both a MySQL and a SQLite3 database and displaying the data in JSON format in the console.  With MySQL, the `Sequelize.fn` function enables me to control the format of the `createdAt` and `updatedAt` fields like this:

```
[Sequelize.fn('date_format', Sequelize.col('updatedAt'), '%m-%d-%Y %H:%i:%s'), 'updatedAt']
```

For example:

```
Article.findAll({
    attributes: [
        'id',
        'title',
        'body',
        [Sequelize.fn('date_format', Sequelize.col('createdAt'), '%m-%d-%Y %H:%i:%s'), 'createdAt'],
        [Sequelize.fn('date_format', Sequelize.col('updatedAt'), '%m-%d-%Y %H:%i:%s'), 'updatedAt']
    ]
})
    .then(tasks => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(tasks, null, 2))
    })
```

returns this:

```
  {
    "id": 27,
    "title": "This is a test title",
    "body": "The main body of the article appears here.",
    "createdAt": "05-28-2017 23:41:42",
    "updatedAt": "05-28-2017 23:41:42"
  }
```

SQLite, however, does not recognize the `date_format` function and throws an error:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: SQLITE_ERROR: no such function: date_format
```

Research suggests that the correct SQLite function is `strftime`, but although no error message appears, the output is `null`.  For example,

```
[Sequelize.fn('strftime', Sequelize.col('updatedAt'), '%m-%d-%Y %H:%i:%s'), 'updatedAt']
```

results in

```
{
  "id": 42,
  "title": "Hello world!",
  "body": "This is stored in SQLite!",
  "createdAt": "2017-05-28T23:19:41.738Z",
  "updatedAt": null
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. You were almost there. Only the parameters to Sequelize.fn were in the wrong order.

with

`[Sequelize.fn('strftime', '%m-%d-%Y %H:%i:%s', Sequelize.col('updatedAt')), 'updatedAt']`

your date should be properly formatted.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!